# Need help understanding return functions and scopes

Tags: javascript

So I'm basically just trying to learn javascript... So I am basically just making functions and testing them to see the results. This code bit should work I think, but it is just returning `NaN`... Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id = "test"> Hello World</p>
  <script>function testFunction(data)
    {
      var x = data;
      var y = 3;
      var z = x + y;
      function testShow(z)
      {
         var b = z * x;
         return  b;
      }  
     return testShow();
  }
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = testFunction(2);
</script>
<button type ="button" onclick ="testFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to put the `document.getElementById`... RIGHT after the return `testShow()`;  When doing that I get the Hello World, but the button is not returning anything or changing the Hello World message...

Comment: I am right now... Too understand what I can do and not do.. I'm trying simple examples, I do not understand how nested functions work, I thought children functions can receive variables from parent variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id = "test"> Hello World</p>
    <button type ="button" onclick ="document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = testFunction(2)">Click me</button>
    <script>
        function testFunction(data){ // just a structure
            var x = data; //2
            var y = 3; // 3
            var z = x + y; //5
            function testShow(aNumber){ // just a structure
                var b = aNumber * x; // 5*2 = 10
                return  b;
            }  
            return testShow(z); // function is executed where aNumber = z
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You want to avoid using the same variable name in a nested function, even though it it is overwritten in the function, it causes confusion.

If you write z as the parameter for testShow, then it is not the `var z = x + y` therefore it is better to change the name

You can put the button above the script, because at the time that you click on the button the script exists.

---

Alternatively, you can write the function in ES6 syntax, and using `this` instead of `var` because it is much easier to read once you understand it.

```
function testFunction(data){
    this.x = data; 
    this.y = 3; 
    this.z = x + y;
    this.testShow = aNumber => aNumber * this.x;
    return this.testShow(this.z);
}
```

What `this.testShow` looks like in ES5 (the version you are writing in)

```
this.testShow = function(aNumber){
    return aNumber * this.x;
}.bind(this);
```

So you can see how much extra we need to write to multiply two numbers

---

My preferred way of creating button listeners.

```
<button id="testButton" type="button">Click me</button>

document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = testFunction(data);
});
```

Now the HTML looks more beautiful

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, both answers were great! I picked yours since you explained it and provided code for a nice visual explanation :D

Comment: Ran into another problem, I am getting the correct results now, HOWEVER, the function is being ran right away, when I open the page it shows 10,  How I want it to function is when I click the button, it will change the paragraph to the correct result... Would I just put the document.getElementById method at the bottom of everything?

Comment: Give me a second

Comment: The tutorials I see are very simple, like function doSomething(){ document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "hello world"; It works correctly, I don't understand how my code is different? Instead of a string, I'm returning the value from the function, it processes it correctly just does it on page load, where as the hello world example waits until the button is pressed...

Comment: Thanks! I got it working, just no idea what is going on, still don't know why the function was auto executing itself, but changing the function to use this.x etc.. worked, although I noticed the "document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = testFunction(2)" wasn't working, I switched the inside " " marks to ' ' and it started working.

Comment: Yeah that was lazy on my side. And the function auto executes because of this line `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = testFunction(2);`in your original code. You are executing code right there, while onclick executes when the button is pressed

Comment: Yeah, I thought just adding that line to the function would make it not execute until the button is pressed, didn't know I could write the method inside the button element. I thought you could only write input or a function.. Thank you very much btw! I learned a lot today!

Comment: Don't get discouraged. Programming can be very hard, but when you solve a problem it becomes very rewarding. I updated how i would have written the button listener so the HTML can look more clean

Answer (score 3):

When you call `testShow`, you don't pass any arguments.

This means `z` (which is the first argument to `testShow` — and masks the other `z` in the wider scope that is the result of `x + y`) is `undefined`.

`z * x` is, therefore, `undefined * 2` which is `NaN` which is what is displayed.

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense, kinda like testFunction(data) isn't completed until I send data too it?  So, how would I pass the variable z from my testFunction() into the testShow() function?  testShow(data){ data = z;} ??

Comment: It's completed, it's just completed without `z` being assigned a useful value. And no. You pass data to it in the same way that you pass data to `testFunction`. `testData(666)`

Comment: I understand what you mean about why it isn't working, so if you can tell me how to pass a function value into a nested function, I will accept this answer!

Comment: Awesome! So just send the testShow() like that, and it will allow me to use the parent function variables?

Comment: @Web_Geeek2018 You either should call `return testShow(x + y);`, or declare it as `function testShow() { … }` without parameters (in which case it  will take `z` from the parent scope).

Comment: Thanks everyone!! I should have thought about function(z) not being the same as the variable z.. I just read that you can use parent variables and just thought making a testShow(z) function would use the variable, but it makes perfect sense why it doesn't work that way now. :D